# Como fazer join de 2 tabelas sem repetir dados?

Tags: sql, sql-server, query

Tenho 2 tabelas, uma chamada `SR7010` e outra chamada `SR3010`. A chave primária das duas é o campo *R7_MAT e R3_MAT.*

A query que estou tentando executar é esta:

```
SELECT R7_FILIAL, R7_MAT, R7_DESCFUN, R7_DATA, R3_VALOR FROM SR7010 AS sr7
INNER JOIN SR3010 AS sr3 ON (sr3.R3_MAT = sr7.R7_MAT)
WHERE sr7.R7_MAT = 997
```

O que acontece é o seguinte: o campo *R3_VALOR* aparece com os dados repetidos, porém os outros campos (que começam com *R7*) aparecem normalmente, e quando o campo `R3_VALOR` altera, os dados dos campos *R7* se repetem, assim sucessivamente.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como fazer para que traga corretamente as informações, ou seja, apenas 3 linhas, como abaixo?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

São registros de alterações salariais/cargo.

Ex: Na 1ª linha, com o cargo de Assist Informatica, na data de *20151029*, está com o salário *50,00*.

Na data de *20151115*, ainda como Assist informatica, salário foi alterado para *55,00*.

Na data de *20151126*, o cargo mudou para Anal. de informatica, com o salário de *60,00*.

O que acontece, é que os dados estão sendo listados 3 vezes (quantidade de registros de alterações realmente existentes), porém o campo valor, por se tratar de outra tabela, talvez, está exibindo o mesmo valor 3 vezes  para então mudar para outro valor e repetir novamente por 3 vezes (quantidade de registros de alterações), e assim por diante.

Quando faço uma busca na tabela *SR7010* pelo campo *R7_MAT* = *997*, o banco me retorna 3 registros. O mesmo ocorre quando faço uma busca na tabela *SR3010* pelo campo *R3_MAT* = *997*. Também retorna 3 registros, por isto estou achando estranho.

Comment: Se os campos data e valor não são relevantes, vc pode tirar eles da consulta e dar um group by R7_DESCFUN

Comment: O problema é que os 5 campos são bem relevantes

Comment: Não seria um caso de somar o campo valor? a relação é de 1-N?

Comment: O que você poderia fazer é utilizar o comando pivot para transformar linhas em colunas e ter uma coluna para cada cargo.

Comment: Sua segunda imagem os dados não tem sentido algum. por exemplo ASSIST.INFORMATICA no dia (R7_DATA)  20151029 tem 3 valores diferentes nesse dia e você selecionou o menor já no dia 20151015 você pegou o do meio. Já o ANAL. DE INFOR você pegou o maior valor, não tem muita logica nisso. No lugar da imagem poste os dados assim ajudaria a entender e simular mais fácil.

Comment: Olhe como alterações salariais. R7_DESCFUN como o cargo, R7_DATA como data da alteração do salário/cargo e R7_VALOR como salário

Comment: Ta muito estranho sua alteração de salario. o cara tem 3 aumento no dia e em outra data tem o aumento do mesmo valor?

Comment: É justamente este o meu problema. O correto deveria ser conforme a 2ª imagem.

Comment: Não deveria ser dia 20151029 = 50 e dia 20151115 = 60? as duas primeiras linhas ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alterei o INNER JOIN para incluir mais relacionamentos e funcionou corretamente.

```
SELECT sr7.R7_FILIAL, sr7.R7_MAT, sr7.R7_DATA, sr7.R7_DESCFUN, sr3.R3_VALOR, sr3.R3_FILIAL FROM SR7010 AS sr7
INNER JOIN SR3010 AS sr3 ON (sr3.R3_FILIAL = sr7.R7_FILIAL AND sr3.R3_MAT = sr7.R7_MAT AND sr3.R3_DATA = sr7.R7_DATA)
WHERE sr7.R7_MAT = 997
```

Answer (score 0):

A unica solução foi criar um cursor da seguinte forma.

```
declare @SR7010 table
(
  R7_FILIAL varchar(20),
  R7_MAT varchar(20), 
  R7_DESCFUN varchar (100), 
  R7_DATA date,
  R3_VALOR numeric(18,2)
)

declare @SR7010_new table
(
  R7_FILIAL varchar(20),
  R7_MAT varchar(20), 
  R7_DESCFUN varchar (100), 
  R7_DATA date,
  R3_VALOR numeric(18,2)
)

insert into @SR7010 values
('0301','000997', 'ASSIST. INFORMATICA', '20151029' , 50.00),
('0301','000997', 'ASSIST. INFORMATICA', '20151115' , 50.00),
('0301','000997', 'ANAL. DE INFORM',     '20151126' , 50.00),
('0301','000997', 'ASSIST. INFORMATICA', '20151029' , 55.00),
('0301','000997', 'ASSIST. INFORMATICA', '20151115' , 55.00),
('0301','000997', 'ANAL. DE INFORM',     '20151126' , 55.00),
('0301','000997', 'ASSIST. INFORMATICA', '20151029' , 60.00),
('0301','000997', 'ASSIST. INFORMATICA', '20151115' , 60.00),
('0301','000997', 'ANAL. DE INFORM',     '20151126' , 60.00)


declare @R7_FILIAL varchar(20), @R7_MAT varchar(20), @R7_DESCFUN varchar (100), 
        @R7_DATA date, @R3_VALOR numeric(18,2), @linha int = 0,
        @Linhafinal int =(select top 1 count(R7_FILIAL)
                            from @SR7010
                            group by R7_FILIAL, R7_MAT, R7_DESCFUN, R7_DATA)


DECLARE db_cursor CURSOR FOR  
select R7_FILIAL, R7_MAT, R7_DESCFUN, R7_DATA
from @SR7010 E
group by R7_FILIAL, R7_MAT, R7_DESCFUN, R7_DATA
ORDER BY R7_DATA 

OPEN db_cursor   
FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @R7_FILIAL, @R7_MAT, @R7_DESCFUN, @R7_DATA  

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0   
BEGIN   

       if(@linha = 0)
       begin
            insert into @SR7010_new 
            Select @R7_FILIAL, @R7_MAT, @R7_DESCFUN, @R7_DATA,( select min(R3_VALOR) from @SR7010 where R7_DATA = @R7_DATA)
            set @linha = 1;
       end
       else
       begin
            set @linha = @linha + 1; 
            if(@Linhafinal = @linha)
            begin
                insert into @SR7010_new 
                Select @R7_FILIAL, @R7_MAT, @R7_DESCFUN, @R7_DATA,(select top 1 t.R3_VALOR from @SR7010 t where t.R7_DATA = @R7_DATA order by t.R7_DATA desc, R3_VALOR desc)
            end
            else
            begin
                insert into @SR7010_new 
                Select @R7_FILIAL, @R7_MAT, @R7_DESCFUN, @R7_DATA,(select top 1 t.R3_VALOR from @SR7010 t where t.R7_DATA > @R7_DATA order by t.R7_DATA desc)
            end
       end
       FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @R7_FILIAL, @R7_MAT, @R7_DESCFUN, @R7_DATA    
END   

CLOSE db_cursor   
DEALLOCATE db_cursor

select * from @SR7010_new
```

Comment: Com o SUM, aparece a quantidade de linhas corretas, porém, como faço para trazer o valor do campo R3_VALOR referente de cada linha? Com o sum, ele soma e repete o resultado da soma para as outras linhas

Comment: Sorry, não vi sua coluna R7_DATA, todos os dados são diferentes.

Comment: Você quer que somar  a coluna ou trazer só uma linha com o valor dela?

Comment: O resultado correto deveria ser como a da 2ª imagem, na pergunta. Cada R7_VALOR relacionada para R7_DATA, que está relacionada à R7_DESCFUN

Comment: Veja a edição com MIN e MAX.

Comment: Não tb...agora os valores se alteram a cada linha, porém, os dados que repetem são os que começam com R7...ou seja, apenas inverteu a situação :(